# Binary quicksort starting bit position

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, sorting

I am reading about binary quicksort at the following location:

http://books.google.co.in/books?id=hyvdUQUmf2UC&pg=PA426&lpg=PA426&dq=robert+sedwick+binary+quick+sort&source=bl&ots=kAYK3_LkCg&sig=BjKk4g68h8xG87Vx2vS_TiUKDQY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uuKzUq4-iY-tB7nZgdgL&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=robert%20sedwick%20binary%20quick%20sort&f=false

Text snippet:

> For full-word keys consisting of random bits, the starting point in Program 10.1 should be the leftmost bit of the words, or bit 0. In general, the starting point that should be used depends in a straightforward way on the application, on the number of bits per word in the machine, and on the machine representation of integers and negative numbers. For the one-letter 5-bit keys in Figures 10.2 and 10.3, the starting point on a 32-bit machine would be bit 27.

My question on above text is:

- Why does the author conclude that the starting point on a 32-bit machine should be bit 27 for 5-bit keys?

Comment: 5 bits resided from 27 to 31 including...

Comment: While I don't know anything about the algorithm, it seems to be as simple a subtracting 5 from 32?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg:  It's big endian bit numbering!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text excerpt is confusing because it is incomplete.

It appears the text assumes a big-endian bit numbering for bits within a machine word.  In big endian bit numbering, bit 0 is the leftmost bit within a word.  The hint comes from the phrase "*the leftmost bit of the words, or bit 0.*"

Therefore, for a 5 bit number held in a 32 bit register, bit 0 of that number would be held in bit 27 of the machine word, for a right-aligned value in a big-endian numbered word.

```
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3   machine word
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1   bit numbers
+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+
|x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x|0 1 2 3 4|  char to sort
+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+
```

Big endian bit numbering is uncommon in most places these days.  IBM POWER / PowerPC still use big endian numbering, as did older big endian architectures such as the TMS9900 / TMS99000 family.